# How am I supposed to access the response of a request that returns a 422 error with a validation message?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a PUT request to an endpoint in order to edit an entity, and if the PUT request fails, a response is returned that contains a validation message. Now I am a bit confused how to access that validation message considering the catch block of a try-catch only accepts an error.

Currently I have:

```
export const updateGame = async (game) => {
    try {
        await request.put('/game', { game });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
};
```

And if that PUT request fails, I get a response that looks like this:

```
{
    error: {
         message: 'Some error message'
    }
}
```

However, I'm not quite sure how am I supposed to access that response considering the request fails and I only console log the error which does not contain that information

Comment: `error.response.data`?